# Can we remove the [ubuntu22.04] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We already have a [22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/22.04) tag. I guess someone accidentally created the [ubuntu22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu22.04) tag. Shall we delete it?

Comment: yes! I have edited the questions that have the tag to remove it - let's hope it stays gone

Comment: Someone asked another question with this tag 10 minutes ago and I just edited it. Can we permanently delete this tag so that new users don't see it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done and I solved the problem with a **tag merge** that also forces an alias for [ubuntu22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu22.04) to be [22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/22.04).  No more [ubuntu22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu22.04) tag!

[image]